# Google Data Studio: Filter inheritance options missing

Tags: looker-studio

I've asked this question on the Data Studio community page with no response, and haven't been able to find the answer elsewhere.

I need to stop 2 charts on a page from inheriting the page level control that I have set. From searching around, it appears that there used to be an option to disable filter inheritance, which would achieve exactly what I need. However, that option seems to no longer be available.

I've tried manually setting chart level filters that include all of the information I need, but they still seem to be overridden by the page level controls I have set. I've tried creating calculated fields that hard code the information I need, but they are also overridden by the page level controls regardless.

The comparison that I need to make is between an individual store's customer churn, and the average churn for all stores. The report is an overall report for all stores, with the ability to choose an individual store from a dropdown control to narrow down the results, so I can't set it up with chart-level filters as that would defeat the whole purpose.

Does the filter inheritance option no longer exist, or does it not apply to controls? Is there another way around this that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance! :)

Screenshot of the filter inheritance options missing:

[No filter inheritance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asWQO.png)

Example Data Studio report:

[Example report](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/23f803e5-4822-475c-9743-43eb6443e4ce/page/szUoC)

UPDATE: I have figured out a temporary workaround, which is to set up a separate data source that does not include the fields referred to within the controls. However, this is not a workable solution for reports with a number of pages and a number of controls added, as it effectively requires a new data source for every control that I need to exclude (and sometimes that isn't possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Group

One way to ensure that the two specific charts (referred to as `Excluded_Charts` in this answer) are not influenced by [Controls](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) (in this case a [Drop-down list](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335992) and a [Date range control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067)) is to [Group](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9209580) all charts except `Excluded_Charts`, which would result in the two charts operating independently from the rest:

- Right-click on a blank space in the Report
- From the drop-down click on `Select` > `All charts and controls on page`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on both charts in `Excluded_Charts` to exclude them from selection
- Right-click on one of the selected charts
- Click on `Group` from the right-click menu
  Additionally, to make sure that the [Date range control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067) does not affect `Excluded_Charts` select both charts in `Excluded_Charts` and change the default date range from `Auto` to `Custom`.

## Ungroup

To reintegrate `Excluded_Charts` back with the rest of the charts in the report:

- Select the grouped charts (selecting a single grouped component will highlight all grouped components)
- Right-click on one of the selected charts
- Select `Ungroup` from the right-click menu
  Additionally, remember to change the default date range of the `Excluded_Charts` back from `Custom` to `Auto`.

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6790e4dd-e23f-4413-84c0-8913dae0300e) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17EERhbcsCIwgaXzckXw90kDIG1yb3euBgYUUrHIeMEs/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution - the issue is that I was looking at filter inheritance rather than controls. [Controls can be limited in scope by grouping them with the charts you want them to apply to.](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7514442)

Thank you very much for your help @Nimantha! I would have never figured this out if you hadn't pointed out that I was referring to filters rather than controls.